# Animate scrollTo firefox and IE issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, firefox

Im using javascript to override my sidemenu on click to slide to div instead of go directly to it. My script is working good on chrome, but it doesnt work on Firefox or IE. Can anyone tell me how can I fix my script so it works on IE and FF?

Here is my code:

```
 $('#sidebar a').each(function(){
            var href = $(this).attr('href');
            console.log(href+" @!#");
            $(this).click(function () {
                event.preventDefault();
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $(href).offset().top
                }, 1000);
            });

        });
                    </script>
```

Comment: check if `$(href)` returning expected result. And please always consider to define "it doesn't work". BTW, debug it and see which variable has not expected value. Looks not that hard to debug it

Comment: @A.Wolff I think this is ok because, when you run the site on ie or ff the links are ok but the animation is gone?!?

Comment: Could you provide a jsFiddle? Why using `if(href=="#team-section")` while the ELSE as same exact code???

Comment: @A.Wolff i cant add a jsfiddle,but i've updated my code - this is the right one - i've mistaked it :S

Comment: One thing for cross browser support, you need to pass event as parameter: `$(this).click(function (event) {...});`

Comment: @A.Wolff http://jsfiddle.net/Yp82f/

Comment: Like said, pass event as parameter to handler, problem solved: http://jsfiddle.net/Yp82f/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it completely different, perhaps your code fails on the event.preventDefault(). I always do preventDefault on the event object passed in the callback.

```
$('#sidebar').on('click', 'a', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $($(e.target).attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Can u give me more explanation how can I use this? I've added your code instead of mine but same thing

Comment: Can you post your html too?

Comment: Yes here is one example of my problem that doesnt work on firefox
http://jsfiddle.net/Yp82f/

Comment: Apparently you didn't read the part about event.preventDefault(), this one works in firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/Yp82f/2/